# How to put a css triangle before a span

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a css triangle before my span and for some reason nothing is showing up at all, any idea what is wrong?

```css
.triangle:before {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid green;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  right: 100%;
  top: 0%;
  position: absolute;
  clear: both;
}

.triangle {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<span class="triangle">Hi</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

You forgot

```
content : '';
```

in your css

```
.triangle::before{
    content:'';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid green;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    right:100%;
    top:0%;
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: I'm happy to hear that ;)

Answer (score 2):

Your span needs to use `class` not `className` and you need to add `content:''` to your before css:

```css
.triangle::before{
    content:'';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid green;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    right:100%;
    top:0%;
    position: absolute;
    clear: both;
}
.triangle{
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<span class="triangle">Hi</span>
```

Comment: Ah ok, you just need the `content:''` then (as long as the classname gets rendered as class once react has finished with it)

Answer (score 2):

You have forgot to pass `content:''` in your css, check updated snippet below:

```css
.triangle::before{
    content: '';
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 3px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid green;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
    right:100%;
    top:7px;
    position: absolute;
}
.triangle{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<span class="triangle">HI</span>
```